# Is "taking a knee" prohibited

Tags: avodah-zarah, bowing-kneeling, martyr, shaat-hadechak

Is it prohibited to perform "taking a knee" for Black Lives Matter?

The question is about the action of taking the knee itself, not to support or rejection of the movement or its ideas. There is a strong presumption in Judaism that the action of kneeling is mostly reserved to doing it in front of G-d, e.g. ואנחנו כורעים ומשתחוים ומודים לפני מלך מלכי המלכים הקדוש ברוך הוא

So the question essentially is: how universal is that presumption? Does it matter that we are talking about genuflection and not full kneeling?

In addition, if the answer to the question above is affirmative, would it be permitted if one faces social ostracism? Or if one's livelihood is threatened (for example, if one fears firing or demotion)?

For completeness, what about if one is physically threatened to do it?

Comment: What possible concerns would you see?

Comment: Perhaps you would consider חילול השם problems with *not* taking a knee?

Comment: Rabbi Joseph Dov Soloveichik felt it was unwise for American Jews to publicly protest the US war in Vietnam as it could lead to anti-Semitism and/or anti-Israel demonstration; his more Americanized brother Aaron was into demonstrations. ("Not just the only Rosh Yeshiva actively protesting on behalf of Biafra, but the only one who knows what it is.") Both knew better than to accuse the other of "desecrating G-d's name." If everything's a "chilul Hashem", nothing's a chilul Hashem.

Comment: @Shalom - updated the question

Comment: Can you explain what "taking a knee" means for people who read this in the future (or even present) and don't have the current events context of your post

Comment: I don't understand your use of חילול השם.  I suspect you are using the phrase differently from how most would use it

Comment: You're asking if it constitutes problems vis-a-vis *kneeling* or other actions that could look like pagan worship? That's an entirely different question than "Chilul Hashem", which is "when people see Jews doing something horrible, we make God look bad." *I don't think that means what you think it does.*

Comment: I am using this in the classical or original sense, not in the sense people use it now, See רמב"ם הלכות יסודי התורה ה

Comment: Instead of having an argument about how you use words special ways, why not just write clearly what you want using words everyone understands right away

Comment: There was no argument. You asked, I explained myself and updated the question.

Comment: you did not explain yourself. why not just write clearly what you want using words everyone understands right away

Comment: It sounds like the gist of your question is "is there any prohibition to kneel", the whole Chillul Hashem part seems to be confusing the question. If you have an answer to whether kneeling is forbidden, then it's simple to follow through (based on type of Issur) as to whether it is a Chillul Hashem.

Comment: As an aside, if you're asking whether an action would be a Chillul Hashem based on the Rambam in Yesodei Hatorah 5, then the answer would simply be (generally) no. See 5:10, where he says essentially that the action has to be done to spite the Torah and Hashem, which isn't occurring in your examples.

Comment: @Salmononius2 - it is a fair point that there are actually 2 questions here: if there is an issur and if there is one, would it be OK to violate it if one's livelihood is on the line. I'll update the question tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Can a Jew be knighted by the Queen? They seem to make you kneel.